# Inverse of non-continuous scale

Tags: inverse

I'm currently struggling with inverting a value on the non-continuous scale

```
-2 0 1 5
```

to a value on the following (inverted) scale

```
5 1 0 -2
```

What I tried before is the commonly suggested approach of

```
value = maxOfScale + minOfScale - value
```

but this seems only to evaluate correctly when using non-negative values.

Is there a fairly straight forward approach for this?

Comment: i am not entirely sure what you want. Do have a list of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and a function that satisfy $f(a_j) = a_{n-j+1}$?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Thanks for your answer! Yes, basically, I'm looking for a transformation function for a given input on the first scale which satisfies the constraint you stated but without the use of a list of elements.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible for an arbitrary list